# tikz picture inside main code or include tikz output

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, compiling, include, resolution

Suppose that someone wants to include a `tikz picture` inside a `LaTeX` document. Suppose that a simple `tikz` code is the following

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[step=1cm,gray!50,very thin] (-1.9,-1.9) grid (5.9,5.9);
  \draw[very thick,->] (0,0) -- (4.5,0) node[anchor=north west] {\bf{x axis}};
  \draw[very thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,4.5) node[anchor=south east] {\bf{y axis}};
  \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4}
    \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {$\mathbf{\x}$};
  \foreach \y in {0,1,2,3,4}
    \draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\mathbf{\y}$};
  \draw[thick, ->] (3,2) arc (0:270:1cm);% syntax (starting point coordinates) arc (starting angle:ending angle:radius)
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with the output

[image]

I was wondering on what's the best in terms of mainly quality and secondly process speed and perhaps memory usage or output file size :

1. To include the `tikz` code inside the document"
2. To produce the picture in a `standalone` code and then import it as a figure using `\includegraphics{tikzpicture.pdf}`

Comment: @JLDiaz : I believe that since the image it's draw and finilized there's probably no obvious reason to change! In terms of resolution or output quality, is there any difference? Also what do you mean by *externalization feature of tikz*?

Comment: That's sounds great and quite helpful! I will take a look!!! Thank's!

Answer (score 2):

Resolution and quality are the same.

As for speed, if your figure changes often (and hence has to be recompiled frequently), the second approach does not provide much speed advantage. If it doesn't change, then the second approach is faster since the tikz code is compiled only once.

Note that your "main" document doesn't require to use tikz, and this is also a speed gain (only the inclusion of the library takes a noticeable time).

However the second approach is more prone to inconsistencies in style, fonts, etc if not done properly. You have to be careful of using the same document preamble (fonts, sizes, etc) to ensure consistency between the text in the document and the text which is part of the figure. To help with this, Tikz has a library called `external` which basically writes to an external file any tikzpicture in your document, with the appropiate preamble and settings, compiles it, and then uses the resulting pdf instead of the tikz code. You can read about it in pgfmanual